# Append int value to string

Tags: string, go, type-conversion, int

I can't seem to find a working solution:
The situation is the following:

```
var s string
n := 1
```

I want to append the int value to the string s.
Then increment or decrement n at some point and append the new value again

So in the end I'd have a string like this:

1213

What I tried so far:

`s = s + string(rune(n))`  // for some reason string(rune(n) is []  aka empty

Comment: `s` is not empty, you've appended a 1 exactly as the code states https://play.golang.org/p/Qu7e41fWPSS. Start with some basics like [Effective Go: Printing](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#printing)

Comment: @DanielHornik Thank you!

Comment: @JimB Thank you! You are right. I basically tried to debug it using fmt.Println(s) and it prints literally nothing. I just started with golang and ignored the basics. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use strconv from the strconv package

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    a := 4 
    b := 3
    c := "1"

    fmt.Println(c + strconv.Itoa(a) + strconv.Itoa(b))
}
```

Or you can use Sprintf from the fmt package:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := 4 
    b := 3
    c := "1"
    c = fmt.Sprintf("%s%d%d",c,a,b)

    fmt.Println(c + strconv.Itoa(a) + strconv.Itoa(b))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!